# Normal Intersection of Parabola

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

If   ($ x_1$,$ y_1$) , ($ x_2$,$ y_2$) & ($ x_3$,$ y_3$) be three  points on the  parabola    $y^2= 4ax$ and the normals at  these points meet  in a point then prove that  $\frac{ x_1 - x_2}{y_3} + \frac{ x_2 - x_3}{y_1} + \frac{ x_3 - x_1}{y_2}$=0.

Normal Equation:

$y=mx-am^3-2am$

Let (x',y') be common points

We get:

$y'=mx'-am^3-2am$

Let $m_1, \ m_2$ & $m_3$ be the slopes at ($ x_1$,$ y_1$) , ($ x_2$,$ y_2$) & ($ x_3$,$ y_3$).

We get

$ \ y_1=\ m_1 \ x_1+y'-\ m_1x'$

$ \ y_2=\ m_2 \ x_2+y'-\ m_2x'$

$ \ y_3=\ m_3 \ x_3+y'-\ m_3x'$

To arrive at the desired result i used

$y'=mx'-am^3-2am$

After this step i used $ \ m_1+ \ m_2+ \ m_3=0$ as $\ m^2$  coefficient is '0' but to no avail

Comment: @Aretino I have posted a parabola problem where normal to three point intersect at one point, i showed the steps i have done but got struck

Comment: The points from where there are three normals to the parabola must reside on the $x$-axis, mustn't they?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe The three points are *on* the parabola.

Comment: @amd Of course, but if their normals meet in $P$, then $P$ must live on the first axis.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Must it? With $a=1$, the normals through $(4,4)$, $(3,-2\sqrt3)$ and $(7-4\sqrt3,-4+2\sqrt3)$ meet at $(9 - 2 \sqrt3, -6 + 4 \sqrt3)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a slightly different approach from yours, we have $\nabla(y^2-4ax)=(-4a,2y)^T$, so in homogeneous coordinates the normal through a point $[x:y:1]$ that lies on the parabola is $\mathbf n=[y:2a:-(x+2a)\,y]$. For the normals through three points to have a common intersection, their scalar triple product $\mathbf n_1\times\mathbf n_2\cdot\mathbf n_3$ must vanish, therefore $$\begin{vmatrix} y_1 & 2a & -(x_1+2a)\,y_1 \\ y_2 & 2a & -(x_2+2a)\,y_2 \\ y_3 & 2a & -(x_3+2a)\,y_3 \end{vmatrix} = -2a((x_1-x_2)y_1y_2 + (x_2-x_3)y_2y_3 + (x_3-x_1)y_1y_3)=0$$ which is equivalent to the desired condition if $y_1,y_2,y_3\ne0$.

To put this in terms with which you might be more familiar, if you negate the last column of the above matrix, you have the augmented coefficient matrix of the system of linear equations of the three normals. This system is overdetermined, so for it to have a solution, the rows of the matrix must be linearly dependent, which is equivalent to the determinant of the matrix being zero.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer

Answer (score 1):

Using $4ax_i = y_i^2$ we can rewrite the statement to be proved as

$\displaystyle\sum_{cyc} y_1y_2(y_1^2-y_2^2) = (y_1-y_2)(y_2-y_3)(y_3-y_1)(y_1+y_2+y_3)$

The parametric form of the Normal at $(at^2,2at)$ is $y+xt = at^3+2at$. If it passes through $(h,k)$, we must have $at^3+(2a-h)t-k=0$

From this we see that if $t_1,t_2,t_3$ are the roots of this equation $\sum t_i=0 \Rightarrow \sum y_i =0$. With this the required statement is readily seen to be true.